# How to always add children before an other one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add `input` dynamically with JavaScript but I want to keep the button `+` at the bottom of all the inputs.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("addEnv").onclick = function(e){
  var inputEnv = document.createElement("input");
  var labelEnv = document.getElementById("labelEnv");
  inputEnv.setAttribute("type", "text");
  inputEnv.setAttribute("class", "input-field env");
  labelEnv.appendChild(inputEnv)
}
```

```css
.form-style-2{
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba($swisscom-blue, 0.7);
}
.form-style-2-heading{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label > span{
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
  color:red;
}

.form-style-2 a{
  display: block;
}
.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}
.form-style-2 input.env, input.vol{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.form-style-2 input.nameModif{
  width: 50% !important;
}


.form-style-2 .input-field:focus{
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #FF8500;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover{
  background: #EA7B00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-2">
    <div class="form-style-2-heading">help me</div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>
        <span>Container name
          <span class="required">*</span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="n1" />
      </label>
    <label id="labelEnv">
      <span>Environment
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e1" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e2" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e3" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e4" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e5" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e6" />
      <button class="addEnv" type="button">+</button>
    </label>
    </form>
    </div>
```

(I don't know why I can't add a field here, I always have problem to transform MeteorJS event to a Snippet event sorry)

So the problem is when I add a field it goes under the button but I want to keep the button at the bottom of the `<label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your prefer `jQuery` then you can use `.insertBefore()`. check below snippet

```js
$('.addEnv').click(function(){
    $("<input type='text' class='input-field env' />").insertBefore($('.addEnv'));
})
```

```css
.form-style-2{
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba($swisscom-blue, 0.7);
}
.form-style-2-heading{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label > span{
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
  color:red;
}

.form-style-2 a{
  display: block;
}
.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}
.form-style-2 input.env, input.vol{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.form-style-2 input.nameModif{
  width: 50% !important;
}


.form-style-2 .input-field:focus{
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #FF8500;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover{
  background: #EA7B00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-style-2">
    <div class="form-style-2-heading">help me</div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>
        <span>Container name
          <span class="required">*</span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="n1" />
      </label>
    <label id="labelEnv">
      <span>Environment
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e1" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e2" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e3" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e4" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e5" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e6" />
      <button class="addEnv" type="button">+</button>
    </label>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: it works like a charm so I'll change my code to JQuery

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild` will always add element inside the container at bottom. Use `insertBefore` rather.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("addEnv")[0].onclick = function(e){
  var inputEnv = document.createElement("input");
  var labelEnv = document.getElementById("labelEnv");
  inputEnv.setAttribute("type", "text");
  inputEnv.setAttribute("class", "input-field env");
  labelEnv.insertBefore(inputEnv, document.getElementsByClassName("addEnv")[0])
}
```

[Here is working link](https://jsfiddle.net/6w4o87he/)

Comment: I have this error `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

Comment: the problem is with Meteor the `this` is not the same `this`as usual. I had problem with that but I upvoted yours and I'l use the JQuery one. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 2):

This code is without jquery. please check i have done changes for you code. you have two mistakes first one is getElementsByClassName gives you array so you need index to add event to button. second you can use insertBefore to insert before the button.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("addEnv")[0].addEventListener("click",function(e){
  var inputEnv = document.createElement("input");
  var labelEnv = document.getElementById("labelEnv");
  inputEnv.setAttribute("type", "text");
  inputEnv.setAttribute("class", "input-field env");
  labelEnv.insertBefore(inputEnv,document.getElementsByClassName("addEnv")[0] )
} );
```

```css
.form-style-2{
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba($swisscom-blue, 0.7);
}
.form-style-2-heading{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label > span{
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
  color:red;
}

.form-style-2 a{
  display: block;
}
.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}
.form-style-2 input.env, input.vol{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.form-style-2 input.nameModif{
  width: 50% !important;
}


.form-style-2 .input-field:focus{
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #FF8500;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover{
  background: #EA7B00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-2">
    <div class="form-style-2-heading">help me</div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>
        <span>Container name
          <span class="required">*</span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="n1" />
      </label>
    <label id="labelEnv">
      <span>Environment
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e1" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e2" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e3" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e4" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e5" />
      <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="e6" />
      <button class="addEnv" type="button">+</button>
    </label>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes with the `labelEnv.insertBefore(inputEnv, document.getElementsByClassName("addEnv")[0])` it works so I upvote because I'll use JQuery

Comment: @Jerome your comfort

Comment: Arrg... You were faster than me... We aswered the exact same thing!

Comment: Isn't non jquery version is copy of my answer?

Comment: @Imad: run the snippet... It's a fixed version of your script.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I don't see any difference thougj ;) you could comment if some answer has minor mistake, not copy.

Comment: @Imad You don't see a new input field appearing whent you click the `+` button ??

Comment: @Imad i didn't copy your answer not i did see your code at all. i just wrote my answer. when you commented here i saw your answer. just now i upvoted you answer

Answer (score 0):

use insertBefore(newItem,existingItem)

```
labelEnv.insertBefore(inputEnv,addEnvElement)
```